# How to split strings within a list into separate strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a list I have.

```
x = [['E,4'], ['F,1']]
```

How to I split the individual subsections of the list into something else that looks like:

```
x = [['E'], [4], ['F'], [1]]
```

Comment: Iterate and split, that all.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [23]: x = [['E,4'], ['F,1']]

In [24]: [[e] for sub in x for s in sub for e in s.split(',')]
Out[24]: [['E'], ['4'], ['F'], ['1']]
```

Comment: Alternatively with `sum`: `[sum((e[0].split(',') for e in x), [])]`

Comment: @fjarri: it's a bad idea to use sum with `[]` - you'd end up making a new list with every addition as the operation uses `__add__` instead of `__iadd__`

Comment: True, but it is easier to read. Depending on the list size this may not be a bottleneck.

Comment: Your numbers are still text.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the kind of question that might be easier to answer with more context. But still, how about:

```
L = [['E,4'], ['F,1']]

output = []
for pair in L:
    x, y = pair[0].split(',')
    output.append([x])
    output.append([int(y)])

>>>output
[['E'], [4], ['F'], [1]]
```

Comment: Cool, an answer that provides what the OP asked for.